# Facebook c# SDK giving small facebook post picture

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook c# sdk for my project

```
  dynamic pageData = client.Get("/"+pageId+"/Posts", new {
            access_token = _userAccesstoken
         });
  var data = pageData[0];
```

In this if there is picture post then the picture which it is returning is small as compared to real picture posted on facebook page.

e.g. this is what I get as picture:

[image: Actual]

[Original small image url](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/q83/s130x130/10516797_1017701491580154_3897437580981541883_n.jpg?oh=9d2f2f0229294758fd456f782d5ff0c6&oe=54CD1A33&__gda__=1421313062_61c291e5db3c0e62a3fffbaded12dbcd)

But this is real picture which I should get:

[image: Desired]

[Original large image url](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10516797_1017701491580154_3897437580981541883_n.jpg?oh=addd4e8b0a30a08d27ac88be8d23d2bf&oe=54D00B55&__gda__=1422070380_dc3a0c5b5a49a857e83549a6e81361a4)

Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: No one had this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I've got, is use the Graph API to return the link for webpage that contain only that picture, and search the page for this string:

```
 <a class="fbPhotosPhotoActionsItem" href="https://
```

This will return the original image that you can download. This is a working code in PHP:

```
function getFullImageURL($url) {
    $crawlerHelper = new CrawlerHelper();
    $response = $crawlerHelper->httpRequest($url);
    $html = $response->getHtml();

    $imageLink = explode('<a class="fbPhotosPhotoActionsItem" href="https://', $html);
    if (count($imageLink) == 2) {
        $imageLink = explode('"', $imageLink[1]);
    } else {
        // This could mean other type of post, like video
        echo 'Image not found';
        return;
    }

    return 'https://'.str_replace('?dl=1', '', html_entity_decode($imageLink[0]));      
}
```